# Conversion of UTC time to LOCAL in SQL Query output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I'm struggling with a SQL query - a basic select statement with a UTC time conversion in the select output. I've done a bunch of searching on this and through all of that have arrived at the following query, but it does not seem to work for me.

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[BaseSource]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Output]
      ,[SessionId]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,(SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,getutcdate(),GETDATE()),[Timestamp])) as LocalTime
  FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[SystemOutput]
  ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

This line is where the magic should be happening, but instead i get a exact match of the Timestamp column value, so no conversion happening at all:

> (SELECT
>   DATEADD(MILLISECOND,DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,getutcdate(),GETDATE()),[Timestamp]))

Does anyone know of how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a good approach.  It assumes you want the time zone *of the SQL Server*.  Also, it assumes that the *current* offset is applicable for all values - which in many cases it is not (due to DST, for example).  Can you please tell us what you are actually wanting to do (whose "local" is it?)  Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Firstly i want to stress that this is simply for my own personal/development use to make my queries and the output of this particular table more legible re. the timestamp. Normally any conversion of UTC time is happening at our application level and i definitely would not be doing a datetime conversion within the SQL query. What i'm looking to do is get local (or PST time) from the timestamp in the SELECT output. I'm hitting our production SQL 2016 server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, understand that `getdate()` returns the local date and time *of the server* - not of the person running the query.  If the server's time zone is set to UTC, then it will indeed return the UTC time.

Since you are running on SQL 2016, and you are asking for the UTC time converted to Pacific time, I suggest you use the built-in [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) statement, as follows:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[BaseSource]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Output]
      ,[SessionId]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Timestamp] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS LocalTime
FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[SystemOutput]
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

Note, the above assumes that the `[Timestamp]` field is a `datetime` or `datetime2`, and that it is a UTC-based value.  The first `AT TIME ZONE` makes an assertion that the given value is in UTC, resulting in a `datetimeoffset`.  The second `AT TIME ZONE` then converts from UTC to Pacific time.

If instead the field is already a `datetimeoffset` type, then the query is even simpler:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[BaseSource]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Output]
      ,[SessionId]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Timestamp] AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS LocalTime
FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[SystemOutput]
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

Also, don't be confused by the word "Standard" in the time zone identifier.  That value covers both standard time and daylight time, as applicable in the Pacific time zone in the US and Canada.

Comment: You the man! This is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint  -  I agree... you're definitely "da MAN!" on his one.  I wish they'd use your explanation and examples in the MS documentation (of course, I might have missed it, as well).